# how to prevent bundler from adding platform info to Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, bundler, platform

every time I run `bundle --without=production` bundler adds platform information `PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32` to `Gemfile.lock` and I have to remove that info manually as I am deploying to Heroku. If I do not remove it, `Gemfile.lock` is not added to repository and causes errors.

how can I prevent bundler from adding platform info to `Gemfile.lock`

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar question - [Can I stop Bundler from adding RUBY VERSION to Gemfile.lock](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36316399/306084) - and it turns out the answer is that it can't be done. Bundler adds this information [within the `to_lock` method](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/8d7b671909d9b75a9e1e64889f6ba45b302e3940/lib/bundler/definition.rb#L305) and there's no conditional to skip that section.

It seems like it would be possible to refactor `to_lock` to control which sections of the lockfile are actually written, but so far this hasn't been enough of a pain point for me to make that effort yet.