# Bundler is removing RUBY VERSION from Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm having the opposite issue to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316399/can-i-stop-bundler-from-adding-ruby-version-to-gemfile-lock). The `Gemfile` has:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.1'
```

At the end of my `Gemfile.lock` file is:

```
RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.1p112

 BUNDLED WITH
    1.12.4
```

But when I run `bundle install` is always deleting `RUBY VERSION` regardless I'm using the same as the development team's version. Even I'm using a more recent bundler version than the used to generate the original `Gemfile.lock` file:

```
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.12.5
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
```

Any ideas how can I stop this?

Comment: Is it in the Gemfile?

Comment: @pixelearth I've updated my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a couple of days I stumbled upon another problem where I had to run `spring stop`. After that it started to generate it correctly.
My bad for suspending my pc and have running those processes for weeks instead of trying the good old shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - at the end of Gemfile.lock there were following lines:

```
RUBY VERSION
    ruby 2.4.1p111

BUNDLED WITH
    1.16.4
```

As long as I was using bundler in version 1.3.0 gem those lines have been automatically removed from Gemfile.lock.

The problem stopped after changing the bundler version to the one pointed by BUNDLED_WITH parameter.

The command I used:

```
gem uninstall bundler & gem install bundler -v 1.16.4
```